# plotly choroplethmapbox doesn't let me subplot

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth, plotly-express

Using different sources, I wrote this code for subplotting two Colombian maps with a summarized quantity, on which I want to display on one side the log10 of the other, but it only works when I put both columns (col=1) on the same value (1). Here's the code:

```
locs = dfd['department']
for loc in counties['features']:
    loc['id'] = loc['properties']['NOMBRE_DPT']

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=1, cols=2, subplot_titles=['Normal distribution', 'Logarithm 10'],
    specs=[[{"type": "mapbox"}, {"type": "mapbox"}]]
)

fig.add_trace(go.Choroplethmapbox(
                    geojson=counties,
                    locations=dfd['department'],
                    z=dfd['cases'],
                    colorbar_title = 'First',
                    colorbar=dict(thickness=20, x=0.46),
                    marker=dict(opacity=0.75)), row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Choroplethmapbox(
                    geojson=counties,
                    locations=dfd['department'],
                    z=np.log10(dfd['cases']),
                    colorbar_title = 'Second',
                    colorbar=dict(thickness=20, x=1.02),
                    marker=dict(opacity=0.75)), row=1, col=1)

fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=20, r=0, t=40, b=40))

fig.update_layout(mapbox1=dict(zoom=3.4, style='carto-positron'),
                  mapbox2=dict(zoom=3.4, style='light'),
                  mapbox_center = {"lat": 4.570868, "lon": -74.2973328})

fig.show()
```

And a photo of what it is showing:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dACuR.png)

Thanks!!!

Comment: You should use `specs` with `mak_subplots`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not present any data, I have created a subplot of the [examples](https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/#mapbox-light-base-map-free-token-needed) in the reference, modified to fit your code. I think you need to configure the mapbox settings for each map as to why both are not showing up. I also need to set up an additional API token for mapbox as it is required in my environment. See [here](https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/#mapbox-access-tokens-and-base-map-configuration) for details.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/fips-unemp-16.csv", dtype={"fips": str})

from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

token = open("mapbox_api_key.txt").read()

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=1, cols=2, subplot_titles=['Normal distribution', 'Logarithm 10'],
    specs=[[{"type": "mapbox"}, {"type": "mapbox"}]]
)

fig.add_trace(go.Choroplethmapbox(
    geojson=counties,
    locations=df.fips,
    z=df.unemp,
    colorscale="Viridis",
    colorbar_title = 'First',
    colorbar=dict(thickness=20, x=0.46),
    marker=dict(opacity=0.75)), row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Choroplethmapbox(
    geojson=counties,
    locations=df.fips,
    z=np.log10(df.unemp),
    colorscale="Viridis",
    colorbar_title = 'Second',
    colorbar=dict(thickness=20, x=1.02),
    marker=dict(opacity=0.75)), row=1, col=2)

fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=20, r=0, t=40, b=40))

fig.update_layout(mapbox1=dict(zoom=3.4, style='carto-positron', center={"lat": 37.0902, "lon": -95.7129}, accesstoken=token),
                  mapbox2=dict(zoom=3.4, style='light', center={"lat": 37.0902, "lon": -95.7129}, accesstoken=token))

fig.show()
```

[image]